# How to get external data into a smart contract

Tags: cleos

Is there any way I can call an external API or a smart contract on other EOS sister chains or other blockchains from within an EOS smart contract.

Or maybe some decentralised service that will monitor an EOS contract and then push a transaction to another chain?

Does EOS have state proofs?

Comment: that's an oracle

Comment: Can I write an Oracle into the contract, or is an Oracle a third party I need to connect with?

Comment: it's difficult, there's no real oracle, only on chain things that are definite, oracle move data from off chain to on chain